# Mapping Zip Code vs. County shapefile in R

Tags: r, leaflet, tiger-lines

I am trying to map the polygons for various geographic areas (i.e. county/zip codes).  Based on what I have found at [this blog](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/04/11/using-r-to-quickly-create-an-interactive-online-map-using-the-leafletr-package/) I can easily accomplish this for counties.

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(leaflet)

url<-"http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010DP1/County_2010Census_DP1.zip"
downloaddir<-getwd()
destname<-"tiger_county.zip"
download.file(url, destname)
unzip(destname, exdir=downloaddir, junkpaths=TRUE)

filename<-list.files(downloaddir, pattern=".shp", full.names=FALSE)
filename<-gsub(".shp", "", filename)

# ----- Read in shapefile (NAD83 coordinate system)
# ----- this is a fairly big shapefile and takes 1 minute to read
dat<-readOGR(downloaddir, "County_2010Census_DP1") 

# ----- Create a subset of New York counties
subdat<-dat[substring(dat$GEOID10, 1, 2) == "36",]

# ----- Transform to EPSG 4326 - WGS84 (required)
subdat<-spTransform(subdat, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

# ----- save the data slot
subdat_data<-subdat@data[,c("GEOID10", "ALAND10")]

# ----- simplification yields a SpatialPolygons class
subdat<-gSimplify(subdat,tol=0.01, topologyPreserve=TRUE)

# ----- to write to geojson we need a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
subdat<-SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(subdat, data=subdat_data)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data=subdat)
```

[image]

But if I run the exact same code with a different file for zip codes

```
url <- "http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2014/shp/cb_2014_us_zcta510_500k.zip"
```

I get a completely different area of the country instead of New York.

[image]

Not sure if someone is more familiar with these datasets and these functions to explain why this difference happens?

Comment: I wonder if when you re-project there is an issue?

Comment: entry 0 in that second shapefile has `ZCTA5CE10 (String) = 36426`. That's Alabama and the plot area on the map is Alabama.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I was under the impression that the first two digits in `GEOID10` corresponded to the fips state code (NY = 36).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given @hrbrmstr noticed that the zip codes returned are in fact zip codes in Alabama this made me second guess my previous assumption on the structure of the `GEOID10` variable.  I discovered [this link](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/guidance/geo-identifiers.html) which says that with the zcta files the `GEOID10` variable is actually just the zip codes so it is not possible to filter the same as the county file.

I figured out another way to filter using the `zip_codes` dataset from the `noncensus` package.  I then substituted the line

```
subdat<-dat[substring(dat$GEOID10, 1, 2) == "36",]
```

for

```
# get zip codes for New York
ny_zips <- zip_codes[zip_codes$state=="NY",]
subdat<-dat[dat$GEOID10 %in% ny_zips$zip,]
```

[image]